# Could not bind non-serializable object to JNDI with IBM Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, jndi

I have a working J2EE application which is successfully deployed in both Tomcat and Glassfish servers. I am trying to deploy the same application in IBM WebSphere 8.5.5.10. But could not start the application due to the JNDI binding errors at context rebind statement in the below line.

InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
context.rebind(String object, Custom Java Object);

Following is the exception stack trace found in logs

**[ERROR] com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CannotBindObjectException: Object is not of any type which can be bound.   (eDynamo.handlers.instancerunner.InstanceRunnerHandler)(21 Nov 2018 11:38:06) 
com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CannotBindObjectException: Object is not of any type which can be bound.
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.processJavaObjectForBinding(Helpers.java:718) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doRebind(CNContextImpl.java:2077) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.rebind(CNContextImpl.java:698) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.rebind(WsnInitCtx.java:233) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.rebind(WsnInitCtx.java:245) ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:?]**

I have checked the source code of com.ibm.ws.naming.util class, enabled trace for com.ibm.ws.naming package and found that the object I am trying to bind is not serializable. As per source code only remote objects needs to be serializable and as per JNDI documentation there is no restriction on non-serializable objects.

Java version:- 1.8_64

Could someone please help me on fixing this issue?

Comment: I do not have access to a console right now, from memory.  You have to define a resource that matches the JNDI name you are using to connect.  Ex. like database, you would go Resources-JDBC in the console.

Comment: Hi Nic. Here I am trying to bind an object to JNDI programmatically. The objects to be bind will be decided at runtime.